# General::munfl - Precision lost in LinearModelFit

Tags: mathematical-optimization, fitting, machine-precision, precision-and-accuracy

I am new to mathematica so I am confused regarding the loss of precision in LinearModelFit. In building a linear model with uora (1 or 2) and encodeSeverity (1,2 or 3)

```
lmfit = LinearModelFit[Transpose[{
    uora, encodeSeverity}],
  {1, urbanOrRural},
  {urbanOrRural},
  NominalVariables -> urbanOrRural
  ]
```

It seems fine but when I look at the ParameterTable and ANOVA Table, the precision is lossed and does not help me with my analysis.

```
In[11]:= lmfit["ParameterTable"]

During evaluation of In[11]:= General::munfl: Exp[-93565.1] is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.

During evaluation of In[11]:= General::munfl: Exp[-1342.79] is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.



In[12]:= lmfit["ANOVATable"]

During evaluation of In[12]:= General::munfl: Exp[-1342.79] is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.
```

[image]

The p-value is reported as 0. and I can't find any help online regarding linear models.
Is there a way to improve the p-value and show it in these tables?
Can anyone help?
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your results.  Instead, I receive the error message that the code is dividing by zero.  Check the documentation of `LinearModelFit`.

Comment: Why do you need a P-value more accurate than calling it zero? You could use the following however:  `1 - N[CDF[FRatioDistribution[1, 120889], 270711/100], 1000]` which gives you approximately  `6.8249467777*10^-584`.